# unable to deploy to cloudrun through cloudbuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm currently trying to deploy an app with a Cloud SQL connection to Cloud Run through Cloud Build, however on the cloudbuild step, I keep getting an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Cloud SQL API could not be enabled.

Even though I've enabled both the CloudSQL and CloudSQL Admin apis; out of further curiosity I've also added the project.owner role to Cloudbuild role, but I haven't been able to figure out/fix this; however, I don't get such errors when I'm running the deploy on my local machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the Cloud Build command that you are running?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, here it is:
gcloud beta run deploy api-service \
            --image $IMAGE_NAME --platform managed \
            --set-env-vars $SOME_ENV_VARS \
            --allow-unauthenticated --region us-central1 \
            --set-cloudsql-instances $PROJECT_ID:us-west2:xyz-db \
            --quiet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running an up to date version of the Cloud SDK? It seems there was a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/136194274) that was recently solved to do with this error.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Corinne. Apparently my local installation was using the newer SDK, while Cloudbuild is using the old. Unfortunately, I can't change the SDK because Cloudbuild is a Google Service. So, I may just have to remove the cloudsql connection from the build process as was recommended in the linked url; well, unless I want to build a custom image just for this,